# toggle when pressing in checkbox_wrapper

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to make the checkbox toggle whenever we press anywhere on the checkbox_wrapper. Here's the jsfiddle of my current code jsfiddle.net/hroj0a04/

Here's the code:

```css
            .box {
            width: 10%;
            display: inline-block;
          }
          
          #wrapper {
            width: 30%;
            border: 5px solid RGB(98,98,98);
   position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
   padding-bottom: 2%;
   margins: auto;
   height: 125px;
          }
    
    #wrapper1 {
            width: 90%;
            border: 5px solid black;
   position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
   margins: auto;
   margin-top: 2px;
   height: 125px;
   padding-top: 2px;
   padding-bottom: 5%;
   pading-left: 2px;
   padding-right: px;
          }
          
          .checkbox_wrapper {
            font-family: arial, helvetica;
            color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
            padding: 0.2em 10%;
            -moz-border-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border: 1px solid rgb(0, 255, 255);
   
   margin-top: 2px
          }
    
   
          
          .checkbox_wrapper:hover {
            background-color: rgb(89, 89, 89);
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 0px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
          }
          
          input[type=checkbox],
          input[type=radio] {
            vertical-align: middle;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 1px;
          }
          
          #checkboxes,
          #acft_data,
          #time_data {
            margin-top: 0.5em;
          }
          
          .center {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
          }
          
          input[type=checkbox],
          input[type=radio] {
            vertical-align: middle;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 1px;
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="wrapper1" style="text-align:center;">
 <div id="wrapper" style="text-align:center;">
  <div checkboxes>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="checkbox_wrapper box">
        <input type="checkbox">1</div>
      <div class="checkbox_wrapper box">
        <input type="checkbox">2</div>
      <div class="checkbox_wrapper box">
        <input type="checkbox">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div checkboxes>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="checkbox_wrapper box">
        <input type="checkbox">1</div>
      <div class="checkbox_wrapper box">
        <input type="checkbox">2</div>
      <div class="checkbox_wrapper box">
        <input type="checkbox">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div checkboxes>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="checkbox_wrapper box">
        <input type="checkbox">1</div>
      <div class="checkbox_wrapper box">
        <input type="checkbox">2</div>
      <div class="checkbox_wrapper box">
        <input type="checkbox">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

Is it possible to do it without too much work or not? Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks and have a nice day

NOTE: I know this isn't a nice code. I started this and still have to mess around with other stuff like for example the checkbox margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the label-element for checkbox-wrapper instead of divs. Then it should work out of the box.

```css
.box {
            width: 10%;
            display: inline-block;
          }
          
          #wrapper {
            width: 30%;
            border: 5px solid RGB(98,98,98);
   position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
   padding-bottom: 2%;
   margins: auto;
   height: 125px;
          }
    
    #wrapper1 {
            width: 90%;
            border: 5px solid black;
   position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
   margins: auto;
   margin-top: 2px;
   height: 125px;
   padding-top: 2px;
   padding-bottom: 5%;
   pading-left: 2px;
   padding-right: px;
          }
          
          .checkbox_wrapper {
            font-family: arial, helvetica;
            color: rgb(17, 17, 17);
            padding: 0.2em 10%;
            -moz-border-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border: 1px solid rgb(0, 255, 255);
   
   margin-top: 2px
          }
    
   
          
          .checkbox_wrapper:hover {
            background-color: rgb(89, 89, 89);
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 0px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
          }
          
          input[type=checkbox],
          input[type=radio] {
            vertical-align: middle;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 1px;
          }
          
          #checkboxes,
          #acft_data,
          #time_data {
            margin-top: 0.5em;
          }
          
          .center {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
          }
          
          input[type=checkbox],
          input[type=radio] {
            vertical-align: middle;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 1px;
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1" style="text-align:center;">
  <div id="wrapper" style="text-align:center;">
    <div checkboxes>
      <div class="center">
        <label class="checkbox_wrapper box">
                <input type="checkbox">1</label>
        <label class="checkbox_wrapper box">
                <input type="checkbox">2</label>
        <label class="checkbox_wrapper box">
                <input type="checkbox">3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div checkboxes>
      <div class="center">
        <label class="checkbox_wrapper box">
                <input type="checkbox">1</label>
        <label class="checkbox_wrapper box">
                <input type="checkbox">2</label>
        <label class="checkbox_wrapper box">
                <input type="checkbox">3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div checkboxes>
      <div class="center">
        <label class="checkbox_wrapper box">
                <input type="checkbox">1</label>
        <label class="checkbox_wrapper box">
                <input type="checkbox">2</label>
        <label class="checkbox_wrapper box">
                <input type="checkbox">3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked out great. Have a nice day!

Comment: Great! I would appreciate if you mark it as the correct answer then.

Comment: it's telling me to wait 2 minutes. I've been trying since before  EDIT- 1 minutes left ( I think we need to wait 10 minutes)